# assigned variables not getting populated in feature file Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, karate, karate-call-single

I'm calling a feature file like this -
Eg.

- def acctNum = db.results[0].XXX
- def retCustMod = call read('classpath:features/core/xxx.feature') {entityId: #(acctNumS),modeOfPayment: #(modeOfPay),  amountValue: #(flowAmt), execstartdt: #(execstartdt), payAhead: #(payAheadFlg), collRefNum: #(refNum),tranId: #(tranId), tranDt: #(tranDt)}

Inside called file, 1 XML is getting called. I'm passing these variables to that XML as a input. but instead of data, the input itself is getting passed to the XML.

Feature file (calling xml)-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5vCk.png)

XML variable assigned -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNdfa.png)

Need some help on the same.

I have tried multiple changes but didn't work.

Comment: sorry your question is too complex for me to understand. if you can simplify it please do so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask